# jQuery - How to select all elements with a set font-family applied to them?

Tags: jquery, css, selector

I need a way for jQuery to return all elements that have the css

font-family:AvantGardeITCbyBT-Bold, sans-serif;

applied to them.

I'm thinking the only way of doing this is looping through all elements and checking if this css is applied to it. Seems a slow way of doing it?

Is there a way of doing this via a jQuery Selector?

Comment: Do you care specifically about this exact string - `font-family:AvantGardeITCbyBT-Bold, sans-serif;`, or looking for elements that are using these fonts, which means an element using a `font-family` of `family:AvantGardeITCbyBT-Bold, sans-serif, Arial` will match as well.

Comment: I'm looking for any element that is using the font AvantGardeITCbyBT-Bold

Comment: $("*").each(function() {
  if($(this).css("font-family") == "AvantGardeITCbyBT-Bold, sans-serif") {
   $(this).ieffembedfix();
  }
 });

This works but is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, you can extend the jQuery selectors with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.extend($.expr[':'], {
     AvantGardel: function(elem){
        var $e = $(elem);
        return( typeof $e.css('font-family') !== 'undefined' && $e.css('font-family') === 'AvantGardeITCbyBT-Bold' );
     },
     SansSerif: function(elem){
       var $e = $(elem);
        return( typeof $e.css('font-family') !== 'undefined' && $e.css('font-family') === 'sans-serif' );
     }
 });    
});
```

and then call

```
$(':AvantGardel').hide();
```

or

```
$(':SansSerif').hide();
```

for instance.

working example: http://jsbin.com/idova3/edit

Comment: `$(':AvantGardel')` is gonna be dead slow.

Comment: @J-P: of course it's slow because you use it just like that. `:AvantGardel` equals `*:AvantGardel` which selects all elements. You should use that selector like `div:AvantGardel` for better performance obviously.

Comment: Yeh, it's also slow because you're running `$.fn.css` twice, which isn't needed. I'd be tempted to implement a [flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) jQuery instance for this purpose too, so that you don't have to construct a new jQuery instance every time.

Comment: im sorry but I still cant get this to work on my webpage. I dont understand why it wont work when w=you have it working on jsbin...

Comment: I've figured out why it wasn't working: There was a non-printed character in the code, so if you copy/pasted, it would not work. I've fixed it.