# Can you map one font to another via css?

Tags: html, css

The majority of the work I do for my company is done through a home-grown CMS, and I often have to override site CSS either with inline styles or with style blocks within my content. A lot of the content items I inherited from previous devs reference a font which we soon are going to no longer embed, but have no sans-serif fallback defined. Is there any way to remap a font, so that if an element calls for Brandon, it will display in Arial, for instance?

There is a site-wide CMS position where I have put a couple of JavaScript bandaids, and if there is a CSS answer to this, I can add it there. I did find a jQuery solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044465/jquery-how-to-select-all-elements-with-a-set-font-family-applied-to-them), but I would prefer something more elegant.

Just trying to avoid editing a couple hundred content items, as they would never allocate one of our DB people to SED it sitewide.

Comment: If this change is intended to be permanent - as in you want to permanently change the font - I highly suggest actually *updating* the `css` and not to patch it with JavaScript.

Comment: Create `.woff`, etc. font files from the new font but name them the same as the current font files

Comment: Yes! Do what @StephenThomas just said! I was thinking the same thing while reading the question.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Unfortunately, there is a lot of bureaucracy involved in releasing site code. Part of the goal is to no longer serve fonts from our CDN, so the idea of renaming a font (as Stephen Thomas suggested) is unfortunately out of the question. As Nick Z said, it would obviously be better to update the CSS, but again, it would be in a great number of individual content items. Things like this arise from time to time, and this time i was just hoping to find an easier way out...

Anyhow, thanks for the suggestions.