# How to detect if CSS @font-face is NOT used on a page?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, fonts, font-face

For the purpose of Javascript based automated unused CSS removal we are looking for a solution to detect if a `@font-face` block is used on a page.

Is there an easy way to verify if a font is in use in the HTML?

The method `getComputedStyle()` would require to test each individual HTML element and would not be efficient.

```html
<style>@font-face {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2"),
       url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff") format("woff");
}</style>
<html> ... </html>
<script>function test_if_open_sans_is_used() { return; }</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[document.fonts.check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFaceSet/check) API can be used to detect font-usage. It depends on a font-string `style weight size font-family`.

To match Open-Sans-Italic:

```
document.fonts.check('italic 14px "Open Sans"');
```

Answer (score 3):

This will help determine all fonts used on a given webpage. You can then use this to determine if your target font has been used.

```
const fontUnstack = (stack, size, style, weight) => {
    if (typeof stack === "string")
        stack = stack.match(/[^'",;\s][^'",;]*/g) || [];

    for (const family of stack) {
        if (document.fonts.check(style + ' ' + weight + ' ' + size + ' ' + family))
            return family;
    }
    console.log('undetected font', fontStyle, fontWeight, fontSize, fontFamily, el);
    return null;
};

const els = document.querySelectorAll('*');
let fonts = {};

for (const el of els) {
    const computedStyles = [
        window.getComputedStyle(el),
        window.getComputedStyle(el, '::before'),
        window.getComputedStyle(el, '::after')
    ];
    for (const computedStyle of computedStyles) {
        const fontFamily = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('font-family'),
              fontSize = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('font-size'),
              fontStyle = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('font-style'),
              fontWeight = computedStyle.getPropertyValue('font-weight'),
              usedFontFamily = fontUnstack(fontFamily, fontSize, fontStyle, fontWeight);

        if (usedFontFamily && !fonts.hasOwnProperty(usedFontFamily))
            fonts[usedFontFamily] = [];
        if (fonts[usedFontFamily].indexOf(fontStyle + ', ' + fontWeight) === -1)
            fonts[usedFontFamily].push(fontStyle + ', ' + fontWeight);
    }
}

console.log(fonts);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! A few notes:

1) it doesn't seem to be reliable (it tests for a <span> width change to detect whether a font is used, some fonts may have the same width as the baseline font)
2) it doesn't discover 'unused' fonts outside the scope of a whole HTML document (i.e. a viewport): it will trigger a font-download for `@font-face`
3) it is slow: it requires to test each individual HTML element

Why wouldn't you use `document.fonts.check` instead of the <span> method?

Comment: Thanks for the input @optimalisatie. So I did edit my response to reflect the document.fonts.check. I had not originally used it for compatibility reasons but it seems to be working in the browsers I was able to test. That being said, this code is intended to be used by a developer in the developer panel of the browser to determine the fonts used in a give page. Not intended to be used in your JS and I can't think of a use case that needing to obtain this info every time a page is run.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API you can use or CSS selector for computed styles. ([Old example with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044465/jquery-how-to-select-all-elements-with-a-set-font-family-applied-to-them))
The only options you have is to iterate over the entire DOM, or simply use the Chrome [css coverage](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage)

If you want to automate your solution you can always [extend Chrome Dev tools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#solutions)